# Setting document_type of log in filebeat stops filebeat restarting

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I am trying to import custom log I have on my server through filebeat and send it over to logstash for use in my ELK stack.

I have set this up to work correctly and it runs fine currently.

However, I am wishing to add a logstash filter for this specific log and so decided to add a `document_type` field for this log to allow me to filter based on it in logstash.

I have done this like so:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/apache2/access.log
  document_type: apache-access

- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/www/webapp/storage/logs/laravel.log

- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /opt/myservice/server/server.log
    document_type: myservice
```

I have added `document_type: myservice` to the log for `myservice`, and believe I have done so according to the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html). Furthermore it is done the same as I have done it for the apache access log.

However when I restart filebeat, it won't start back up again. I have tried looking at the log for filebeat - however there doesn't seem to be anything in there about why it won't start.

If I comment out `document_type: myservice`, like this `#document_type: myservice` and then restart filebeat it boots up correctly which means it must be something to do with that line?

**Questions:**

Am I doing something wrong here?

Is there an alternative method I could use to apply my logstash filter to this log only other than using `if [type] == "myservice"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document_type` is a good approach to applying conditionals in Logstash. An alternative method is to apply [tags](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#_tags) or [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields) in Filebeat.

The problem with your configuration is the indentation of the `document_type: myservice` that you added. Notice how the indentation is different than the `document_type: apache-access`. The `document_type` field should be at the same level as `paths` and `input_type` as they are all prospector options.

You can test your config file with `filebeat.sh -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -e -configtest`.

You can also run your config through a tool like http://www.yamllint.com just to check that it's valid YAML.

Comment: Absolute life saver.